# How to redirect to sitemap.php from htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, sitemap

I am using htaccess coppied from wordpress.

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule . index.php [L]

It works fine.

I would like to add a script to redirect to sitemap.php file if user requests sitemap.xml.

I tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-^sitemap.xml$` but didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the rule BEFORE that set of rules:

```
RewriteRule sitemap\.xml sitemap.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: The [L] flag means last, which means that if that rule is triggered, the rewrite engine should not read and process any more rules. Once the request for sitemap.xml matches that rule and is rewritten to sitemap.php, Apache does not read the rest of the rules that would rewrite the request to WordPress.